# Postgresql query a weeks worth of data based on a calendar day regardless which one

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

In PostgreSQL, how could I get the dates of all days in a week, using the date of a single day as input?  For example, imagine a user clicks on on a day in a calendar user interface widget.  That highlights the entire week.

I want to write a query that pulls all rows from a table where a date column matches the date from any day in the highlighted week, regardless of whether the user selected Monday, Wednesday, etc.

Comment: can you post the attempts you have already made?

Comment: Does the mapping of one day to the rest of the days in the week *have* to happen in SQL?  Could you do it in the logic of your application?

Comment: --select * from timetable where clockin > current_date - interval '7 days' and employee_id =32
--select * from timetable where clockin > now()::date -8 and employee_id = 32 order by clockin asc
-- select * from timetable, date_trunc('week', now()::date) where employee_id = 32
-- select *, extract(week from clockin) as week, extract(month from clockin) as month from timetable where employee_id = 32

Comment: I got it. If anyone ever run into the same problem here is how I solved it. SELECT * FROM timetable WHERE extract(week from clockin) = extract(week from date '2017-05-29') and employee_id =32

Comment: As pointed out in the answers below, you should define what a "week" is. In many countries, a week starts on Monday, while in others (including the US), it starts on Sunday. There are probably a few other cases.

Answer (score 3):

You should combine the week **and** year to make the query stable even on the end/start of a year. E.g.:

```
select *
from some_table
where to_char(some_date_column, 'iyyy-iw') = to_char(date '2017-06-06', 'iyyy-iw')
```

`iyyy` and `iw` is the [ISO week numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Week_numbering). The ISO week always starts on Monday.

or using the `extract` function:

```
select *
from some_table
where (extract(isoyear from some_date_column), extract(week from some_date_column)) 
      = (extract(isoyear from date '2017-06-06'), extract(week from date '2017-06-06'))
```

Note that `extract(week ...)` is always the ISO week. There is no corresponding "non-iso" keyword for the `extract()` function

Answer (score 1):

Your best option would be `date_trunc('week', ts)`, like in

```
WHERE date_trunc('week', ts_col) = date_trunc('week', ?)
```

However, this won't use indexes on `ts_col`. And `date_trunc('week', ts_col)` is only index-able if `ts_col` is `timestamp [without time zone]`. `timestamptz` (or `timestamp with time zone`) is not able to use `date_trunc()` based expression indexes. But you can make this [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) with:

```
WHERE ts_col BETWEEN date_trunc('week', ?) AND date_trunc('week', ?) + interval '1 week'
```

Note that `date_trunc('week', ...)` uses the ISO concept of a week, i.e. all of its weeks start on Monday. If that's not good enough for you, you can tweak the following expression: `date_trunc('day', ts) - interval '1 day' * extract(dow from ts)`. This will calculate f.ex. the week start when weeks start on Sunday. If you're aiming other than Sunday, just use some math on the expression above, like:

```
select date_trunc('day', ts) - interval '1 day' * extract(dow from ts) "sunday",
       date_trunc('week', ts) "monday",
       date_trunc('day', ts) - interval '1 day' * ((extract(dow from ts) + 5)::int % 7) "tuesday",
       date_trunc('day', ts) - interval '1 day' * ((extract(dow from ts) + 4)::int % 7) "wednesday"
```

http://rextester.com/KZX2905